# MVC 5 remote validation not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, metadata, remote-validation

I'm trying to implement remote validation in MVC. I have read several tutos and questions already posted here, but there is no answer.

*Controller :*

```
public class GroupsController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestRemoteValidation(string Name)
    {
        return Json(false);
    }
}
```

*View :*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Defaults", FormMethod.Post))
{
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enregistrer" />
}
```

*And Model :*

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nom du Groupe")]
    [Required]
    [Remote("TestRemoteValidation", "Groups", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Remote fired")]
    //[CustomRemoteValidation("TestRemoteValidation", "Groups", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

*Generated HTML Code:*

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-remote="Remote fired" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote-type="POST" data-val-remote-url="/Groups/TestRemoteValidation" data-val-required="Le champ Nom du Groupe est requis." htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
```

I'm using `Metadata` because it's an entity-->not the problem, I checked with an other ViewModel and it's the same.

`[Required]` and `[StringLength(10)]` are fired.
When I put a breakpoint in `TestRemoteValidation`, nothing happens.

For instance I'm able to perform the remote validation with a custom remote attribute class and `Model.IsValid` override, but I don't understand why this way doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. Have you included the scripts for client side validation? Is client side validation enabled

Comment: Yes js scripts are bundled, client side validation enabled-->confirmed with working other validation attributes

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console when you edit the textbox?

Comment: I've just tested, No. I cleaned Visual Studio directories and browser cache with no success...Do you think it could be linked with I don't know, assemblies versions or use of Identity? I really don't understand why it works with a custom validation attribute and not with `[Remote]`

Comment: Its client side code :) What is the actual html generate by your `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`?

Comment: Post edited with my actual code and HTML generated code

Comment: Except for the `htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }"` - its `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })` - not, `new { htmlAttributes = new { ... }}`, your code works fine, so if its not working then its due to something your have not shown us

Comment: there has to be backend code because your remote attribute is using "httpPostmethod = POST".... hence post....

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me either. This is a krap implementation. It should work as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Vehicule` is the `@model` being used in the view

```
@model Vehicule
```

then the controller should expected that model

```
public class DefaultsController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var model = new Vehicule();
        return View(mdoel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Vehicule model) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            //...do something
            //..possible redirect 
        }
        //if we get this far something is wrong with data
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The model binder will take validation into account when binding the model from the request.

Comment: No I don't think so, `Model.IsValid` is equal to true because attribute validation isn't done...Even `TestRemoteValidation` is false, the `Model.IsValid` code is performed.

Answer (score 0):

add

**[AllowAnonymous]**
to

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestRemoteValidation(string Name)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have included below libraries and in correct order in your view

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

these libraries are required for remote validation to work.